# how to insert value in jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery

```
$("input[name=search]").click(function(){
        addCartWindow('pickup', 'Delivery');
        addCartHeader('pickup', 'Address');
        addCartDetails('pickup', $("input[name=address]").value);
    })
```

HTML

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
      <input type="text" name="address" class="span9">
      <input type="button" name="search" class="span2" value="Verify Address" class="btn">
      <div class="span1" id="pickup_price"></div>
 </div>
```

I think something was wrong in this

```
addCartDetails('pickup', $("input[name=address]").value);
```

How can i use it for value ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `$("input[name=address]")` is a jQuery object, you need to use jQuery method which is **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** instead of `value` to get the value of your `input`:

```
addCartDetails('pickup', $("input[name=address]").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
addCartDetails('pickup', $("input[name=address]").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the DOM element you can use get():

```
addCartDetails('pickup', $("input[name=address]").get(0).value);
```

Although in this case val() is more adequate if you just want the value.